# R Error: Could not find function "contour_plot"

Tags: r, installation, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language.

I am following this link over here (https://dtkaplan.github.io/RforCalculus/graphing-functions.html) and trying to produce the following plot:

[image]

I tried to install the required library and then run the code to produce this plot:

```
install.packages("mosaic")

library(mosaic)

contour_plot(
    sin(2*pi*t/10)*exp(-.2*x) ~ t & x, 
    domain(t = range(0,20), x = range(0,10)))
```

But this produces the following error:

```
Error in contour_plot(sin(2 * pi * t/10) * exp(-0.2 * x) ~ t & x, domain(t = range(0,  : 
  could not find function "contour_plot"
```

I tried to re-install this package a few times, but the error keeps persisting.

**Can someone please show me how to fix this?**

Thanks!

```
sessionInfo()

R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] mosaicModel_0.3.0 mosaicCalc_0.5.1  mosaicCore_0.9.0  mosaic_1.8.3      ggridges_0.5.3   
 [6] mosaicData_0.20.2 ggformula_0.10.1  ggstance_0.3.5    dplyr_1.0.6       Matrix_1.2-18    
[11] ggplot2_3.3.5     lattice_0.20-41  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] ggrepel_0.9.1     Rcpp_1.0.7        tidyr_1.1.3       prettyunits_1.1.1 ps_1.5.0         
 [6] rprojroot_2.0.2   assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.27     utf8_1.1.4        ggforce_0.3.3    
[11] R6_2.5.0          plyr_1.8.6        backports_1.2.1   labelled_2.9.0    pillar_1.6.1     
[16] rlang_0.4.10      lazyeval_0.2.2    curl_4.3          rstudioapi_0.13   callr_3.7.0      
[21] readr_1.4.0       stringr_1.4.0     htmlwidgets_1.5.3 polyclip_1.10-0   munsell_0.5.0    
[26] broom_0.7.6       compiler_4.0.3    pkgconfig_2.0.3   pkgbuild_1.2.0    htmltools_0.5.1.1
[31] tidyselect_1.1.0  tibble_3.1.2      gridExtra_2.3     fansi_0.4.2       crayon_1.3.4     
[36] withr_2.4.1       MASS_7.3-53       grid_4.0.3        gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_1.0.0  
[41] DBI_1.1.1         magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1      cli_2.5.0         stringi_1.5.3    
[46] farver_2.0.3      remotes_2.4.0     leaflet_2.0.4.1   ellipsis_0.3.2    ggdendro_0.1.23  
[51] generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.8       tools_4.0.3       forcats_0.5.1     glue_1.4.2       
[56] tweenr_1.0.1      purrr_0.3.4       hms_1.0.0         crosstalk_1.1.1   processx_3.5.2   
[61] yaml_2.2.1        colorspace_2.0-0  haven_2.4.3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own version of `contour_plot` with the same functionality with CRAN-based packages:

```r
library(geomtextpath)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(hrbrthemes)

contour_plot <- function(f, xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1)) {
  
  xvals <- seq(xlim[1], xlim[2], length.out = 500)
  yvals <- seq(ylim[1], ylim[2], length.out = 500)
  df    <- expand.grid(x = xvals, y = yvals)
  df$z  <- f(df$x, df$y)
  
  ggplot(df, aes(x, y, z = z)) +
    geom_contour_filled(alpha = 0.3) +
    geom_textcontour(hjust = 0.75) +
    theme_ipsum()
}
```

The first argument needs to be a function of two vectors:

```
contour_plot(f = function(x, y) { sin(2 * pi * x / 10) * exp(-.2 * y) }, 
             ylim = c(0, 10),
             xlim = c(0, 20))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The function `contour_plot` is only included in the Development version of `mosaicCalc`. You can try to install it using

```
remotes::install_github("ProjectMOSAIC/mosaicCalc", ref="beta")
```

See also this issue on their [github-page](https://github.com/ProjectMOSAIC/mosaicCalc/issues/4).

Comment: Thank you so much! Were you able to plot this picture?

Comment: remotes::install_github("ProjectMOSAIC/mosaicCalc", ref="beta")

Comment: library(mosaicCalc)

Comment: contour_plot(
    sin(2*pi*t/10)*exp(-.2*x) ~ t & x, 
    domain(t = range(0,20), x = range(0,10)))

Comment: But this produces the following error:  Error in is.finite(if (is.character(from)) from <- as.numeric(from) else from) : 
  default method not implemented for type 'list'

Comment: Could you please suggest what to do? thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing loading the library after installing the package?

```
library("mosaic")
```

Comment: @ Toulene: Thank you for your answer! I tried this but it still didn't work. Were you able to produce this plot? Thank you so much!

Comment: neither "mosaic" or "mosaicCalc" have that function. The package "admixturegraph" seems to have a contour_plot function but I dont know if is the same one your book is using.
Have a look at this link in case any of the packages listed here is the one with the function you are looking for: https://rdrr.io/github/dtkaplan/mosaicUSAFA/f/inst/tutorials/MMAC-Chapter-1/MMAC-Chapter-1.Rmd